# Visual Studio 2019 does not notify me of an error until I recompile

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, compiler-errors

On the VB.NET project in Visual Studio 2019, It seems that everytime I need to edit out a function so I can put the argument, like from `Sub StartRDebugThread()` to `Sub StartRDebugThread(ByVal DebugEnable As Boolean)`, it only scans for the current file and (I think) all the opened files, showing me that there is no error.

However, as soon as I compile, it seems to be scanning the whole project for errors, so it will tell me that the compilation has failed. Here's the screenshot of Visual Studio 2019 showing the window [before compilation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXan3.png), and [after compilation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHgBj.png)

However, if I made a mistake while editing in a function, it would tell me that there is an error immediately. I find this annoying, because I have to figure out which function is using the edited one by clicking on the `<number> References`, and double-clicking each function.

How can I get Visual Studio 2019 to always tell me that the calls must be updated everytime I edit the arguments inside the function in a way that I should update the calls?

Comment: Have you set [`Option Strict On`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29985039/1115360)?

Comment: I believe you are correct that, while you are typing, VS 2019 only checks the open files for problems, while earlier versions checked all files. I assume this change was made to improve performance and I don't know of a way to revert it.

Comment: Thanks for the information @Blackwood!